# Can a blocking send() on a socket wait for ever?

Tags: sockets

I have an issue to fix in the biggish chunk of code with which I am still not very familiar, so sorry if my question is not very well formulated...

The code  contains 2 processes communicating via sockets. Each process contains a number of threads which use recursive mutexies for data protection. When run over a long period of time the code hangs  - according to the dump I have a thread blocked waiting on a mutex while another thread holds it and appears to be stuck within a send() - I've checked and the send() is a blocking.
However, I was told that a thread CAN NOT block on a send() forever - if a receiving peer "dies", the fact that the connection no longer exists will be detected and send() will eventually return with an error code - this seemed to make sense as I would have thought that there should be some "I am alive" messages exchanged between connected peers.

But when I "googled", it seemed to me that this is not true - if send() blocks because there is no space in the network buffer and my peer **"has died" without issuing close(), my send() will actually be blocked forever**. ( And "I am alive" messages are not exchanged by default...?)

If someone could confirm/explain what happens to a blocking send() when a receiving peer "dies", I would be very grateful.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the peer dies unexpectedly, it can take a long time for the OS to detect it and invalidate the socket connection.  You can avoid the issue by using timeouts in your code.  Switch to non-blocking sockets.  Or use `select()` to detect if the socket is writable before calling a blocking `send()`.  Or use the `SO_SNDTIMEO` option of `setsockopt()` to set a timeout on blocking sends.  Or enable TCP keepalives.

Answer (score 1):

You are right and your googled resource is wrong. send() blocks while the local socket send buffer is full. If the peer computer has crashed it will stop sending ACKS to all the data that is presently in the socket send buffer that TCP is already trying to send, so the local TCP will eventually reset the connection and unblock the send. This is why sending is the only reliable way to detect a failed connection.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using TCP, because with UDP the send should not block. As long as you don't get  a TCP FIN or RST from the peer the connection is not considered closed and thus the send continues to block. This situation may happen if the peer hangs somewhere too, if the peer computer crashed or if the  network connectivity to the peer got lost. You might use the TCP_KEEPALIVE socket option to make the TCP stack send keep-alive messages, but even in this case it usually takes hours to notice lost connectivity (default timeout for keep-alive is often 2 hours).

Edit thanks to @EJP and @WarrenDew: If the peer does not accept data anymore the window size will go to 0, but the sender will probe it often enough so that it detects network problems or crash of machine. So it can still hang forever if the peer stalls, but the peer must be still alive and reachable.

Comment: It can't happen if the peer has crashed or the network has failed, and it won't take two hours to notice.  Both these statements only apply to receiving.

Comment: @EJP: are you sure? I think if the peer has a full receive buffer, it will set the window size to 0 but ack all received packets. The windows size of 0 will cause the sender to stop sending, e.g. there will be no ACKs missing because the sender did not send anything new. And if then the machine crashes or the network connection fails there will be no more window updates. So yes, network or machine failures alone will not trigger the problem, but they can make it stay.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich As long as the receiver's window size is 0, the sender will send periodic window probes.  A receiver machine crash or network connection failure will still be detected.

Comment: @WarrenDew: Thanks for clarification, I've learned something today.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. 
In my case sockets are used for communication between 2 processes on the same device, so my peer would be alive and reachable, but the thread that consumes the data may well have stalled  - AFAIU from your posts in this case my send() could indeed block forever.  Tomorrow I will be looking at the problem again - if I solve it, I'll post the results ...Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As EJP says, if the receiving machine dies after filling its receive buffer, the sender will detect that because its periodic window probe packets will not receive acknowledgements.

However, if the receiving machine is fine but the receiving application hangs - which might count as "has died" according to your Google source - that receiving application will stop consuming data but its machine will still continue to ack window probes.  The hang will thus be propagated to the sending application.  This may be what is happening in your case.